# How to communicate with Shopify Storefront and add JS snippet to Product Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

I would like to ask someone who had experience with Shopify App development how to inject JS script into product.template.liquid under "Add to cart button" when a Toggle button is clicked from React component.

I have already set up an app using Node.js and React (Polaris framework) and I can connect and authenticate with Shopify. I also wrote the JS script that is working when I add it directly to the product.template.liquid page. Now I would like to connect these two.

The script is showing a fake count of viewers on the page.

What I would like to do is to display this script if this.state == enabled and hide the script if this.state == disabled.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how important it is for you to directly add the Script inside product template, but doing so is possible using [Asset resource](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset) from Shopify REST API. You can update the **product.template.liquid** file using **PUT** request. Sample request from [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/asset#update-2020-07)

```
PUT /admin/api/2020-07/themes/828155753/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "templates/index.liquid",
    "value": "<img src='backsoon-postit.png'><p>We are busy updating the store for you and will be back within the hour.</p>"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ScriptTag to include your JavaScript snippet. You can add and remove Script Tag from client store based on your Toggle button. This solution is much cleaner in my opinion. A sample request from Shopify Docs to create [Script Tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag).

```
POST /admin/api/2020-07/script_tags.json
{
  "script_tag": {
    "event": "onload",
    "src": "https://djavaskripped.org/fancy.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. This is awesome!

I managed to create a scriptTag using GraphQL mutation following the thread you gave and tutorial from here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/learn-the-graphql-admin-api

How would I now load the script from the scriptTag? 
ScriptTag has a property: 

"event": "onload"
The DOM event that triggers the loading of the script. Valid values: onload.

I am using this property in my js script like that: 

<body onload="startTime()"> 

If I wanted to load the script on app install, how would I do it?

Comment: Would I need to use the apollo in any way to make this possible? I have read the tutorial from here https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/fetch-data-with-apollo but I am not sure how to apply these examples to my need.

Comment: @DigitalDom `event: onload` means that is when your JavaScript will be included in Shopify store of your client. Inside the JS file ( URL that you used when creating Script Tag) just write your normal JavaScript code as you did for Product.liquid.

Comment: thank you very much. 

For others in the future who have a similar issue. There was a guy here in this thread : 
https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Mutation-How-to-add-script-tag-to-shop-immediately-when-app-is/m-p/841407 . He managed to do something similar. Maybe its going to be usefull for you.